# SendGrid copy template from Subuser to Parent Account

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I need to copy some my Dynamic Templates from Subuser to my ParentAccount.

Can I do it? Or I can't?

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like It is not supported not. I just continue using the sub-user to store my templates.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did the same after all :(

Comment: I see that you can copy/paste the HTML code. I'm going to give it a try https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/partners/account-migration#migrate-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.
You need to create an API Key on your SubUser that can read your Dynamic Templates. Once done, get it by ID with your subuser API Key, then call another API to create a Dynamic Templates with you Parent account API Key.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/transactional-templates/retrieve-a-single-transactional-template

https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/transactional-templates/create-a-transactional-template